# Copy Sites Pages from one collection to another using PNP

Tags: pnp-powershell

I created over 50 Modern pages in one site collection, to realize they would be better housed in another site collection.

Can I copy/move these pages from one collection to another ( or copy/move the whole Site Pages library ) using PnP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to move the pages

```
Param(
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Inputparameter",Position=1,Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$sharepointUrl,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Inputparameter",Position=2,Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$targeturl,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Inputparameter",Position=3,Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$Sourceurl,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Inputparameter",Position=4,Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$SourceDocumentLib,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Inputparameter",Position=4,Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$TargetDocumentLib
)
function Copy-sharepoint
{
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$sharepointUrl,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$targeturl,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$Sourceurl,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$SourceDocumentLib,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$TargetDocumentLib,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$UserName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$Password,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$cred
)
   #create secure password
$sPassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Sourceurl -Credentials $cred
$Files= Find-PnPFile -List $SourceDocumentLib -Match *
Disconnect-PnPOnline
$Loginsource =$false
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $sPassword)
$webClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
$webclient.Proxy = $null
foreach($file in  $Files)
{

    If($file.Name -eq "ACE-Tech-Talks.aspx")
    {
    $pageUrl = $sharepointUrl+$file.ServerRelativeUrl
    $UniqueFileName = $file.Name
    $ByteArray=$webClient.DownloadData($pageUrl)
    $tfolderWithname= ($pageUrl -split $Sourceurl)[1]
    $tfolderwiths =($tfolderWithname -split $UniqueFileName)[0]
    $tfolderrmstr =$tfolderwiths.TrimStart("/")
    $tfolder =$tfolderrmstr.TrimEnd("/")
    $fstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]($ByteArray)  
     If($tfolder -eq $null)
    {

        If($Loginsource -eq $false )
        {
            Connect-PnPOnline -Url $targeturl -Credentials $cred
            $Loginsource =$true
            Add-PnPFile -FileName $UniqueFileName -Folder $TargetDocumentLib -Stream $fstream
        }
        else
        {
            Add-PnPFile -FileName $UniqueFileName -Folder $TargetDocumentLib -Stream $fstream
        }
}
else
{
  If($Loginsource -eq $false )
        {
            Connect-PnPOnline -Url $targeturl -Credentials $cred
            $Loginsource =$true
            Add-PnPFile -FileName $UniqueFileName -Folder $tfolder -Stream $fstream
        }
        else
        {
            Add-PnPFile -FileName $UniqueFileName -Folder $tfolder -Stream $fstream
        }
}

    }
    }
    }
$cred=Get-Credential
$UName=$cred.UserName.ToString()
$Pass =$cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
Copy-sharepoint -UserName $UName -Password $Pass -cred $cred -sharepointUrl $sharepointUrl -targeturl $targeturl -Sourceurl $Sourceurl -SourceDocumentLib $SourceDocumentLib -TargetDocumentLib $TargetDocumentLib
write-host "Copying of file complete"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Copy-SharePointPage
{
    param([string]$SourceSiteUrl, [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$SourceSiteCredential, [string]$TargetSiteUrl, [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$TargetSiteCredential, [string]$Page)

    $TempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SourceSiteUrl -Credentials $SourceSiteCredential;
    Export-PnPClientSidePage -Force -Identity $Page -Out $TempFile

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TargetSiteUrl -Credentials $TargetSiteCredential;
    Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path $TempFile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sourceURL -Credential $O365Credential

Get-pnpprovisioningtemplate -out $outputXMLLocation\pages.xml -handlers PageContents -IncludeAllClientSidePages

apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate $outputXMLLocation\pages.xml
```

Try above commands. For more details check the [Blog](https://vishsharepointzone.blogspot.com/2020/04/copy-sharepoint-online-site-pages.html)