# SharePoint Site Pages migration from SPO teams site to SPO communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages, sharepointmigrationtool

I am looking to migrate SharePoint online site pages to another site collection. The source is a SharePoint online team site and destination is SharePoint online communication site. I have tried using the SharePoint migration tool and the site page is successfully migrated however on clicking it's throwing error and not opening the site page.

Can someone guide me how can i resolve this issue or any other way that you would like to suggest based on your past experience ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Migration Tool doesn't support SharePoint online to online migration.

You may need to using code to achieve this:

[Copy Sites Pages from one collection to another using PNP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/246718/copy-sites-pages-from-one-collection-to-another-using-pnp)

https://www.netwoven.com/2018/11/28/how-to-migrate-sharepoint-online-modern-client-side-pages/

Comment: @Juli_MSFT: I have gone through the SharePoint migration tool and in the past it did not provide the option to migrate from SP online to online but now it does through the JSON and XML file option provided by the tool. I migrated site pages library from one SPO site to another SPO site.